# Django Inline for admin panel in foreign relationship with admin.TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-admin

models.py

```
class Parent (models.Model):
    id = ......
    name = ...
    address = ...


class Child (models.Model):
   id= ...
   parent = models.ForeignField(Parent)
```

Here in this schema, is it possible to bring Parent form inside Child schema to make editable by admin.Tabularline ? I know it is possible to bring Child Schema into parents schema and make editable. But I am looking for vice versa. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want. But I hope it will help you.

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child


@admin.register(Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    inlines = [ChildInline]
```

Comment: No, i want to inline parent under child model. Exactly opposite of this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find way to inline parent under child model. So, I made custom form where I define `fields` = '**all**' and then it kind of worked for me.

In admin.py

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Child
      fields = '__all__'

class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = ChildForm

admin.site.register(Child, ChildAdmin)
```